# preset print setting for Chrome Preview

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, printing

I am wondering is there any way to preset the "Margins" setting in Chrome Print Preview (with Ctr+P) to none?

I wish to have printout in receipt paper, since its width is really limited, all printout have to be set its margins to none prior to print them out.  If this setting can be prefix by CSS or scripts, it would be great for my users.

Any ideas are welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no you can disable the print preview of chrome and set it up  the default for the traditional print menu!

To disable google print preview  go to Yes and no you can disable the print preview of chrome go to about:flags just put it in your google chrome browser. cntrl+F type print and look for disable print preview!

Now restart chrome browser (close all windows) And pres cntrl+p click preferences then features then select letter size!  make your changes then go to back to printing shortcuts and click save now cntrl+p and then click print and voila your done!